# Function only evaluates first row of R data table

Tags: r, function, dplyr, datatable

I have a simple data table `apple` that has numerous instances of numbers shortened as 40.08B, 40.08M, 400.08K, etc. I need to remove these letters and replace them with the appropriate number of zeros (i.e. 400.08K becomes 400080), so I wrote the following code:

```
apple2 <- dplyr::case_when(
  stringr::str_detect(apple[,-1], 'B') ~ readr::parse_number(as.character(apple[,-1]), na = c("", "NA")) * 1e9,
  stringr::str_detect(apple[,-1], 'M') ~ readr::parse_number(as.character(apple[,-1]), na = c("", "NA")) * 1e6,
  stringr::str_detect(apple[,-1], 'K') ~ readr::parse_number(as.character(apple[,-1]), na = c("", "NA")) * 1e3,
  TRUE ~ parse_number(as.character(apple[,-1]), na = c("", "NA"), trim_ws = TRUE) 
)
```

The code works as expected in finding and converting the strings into appropriate numbers, but it only runs on the first row of the data table. In addition, it removes the headers. The error message is the following:

```
argument is not an atomic vector; coercingargument is not an atomic vector; coercingargument is not an atomic vector; coercing[1]
```

I've tried figuring this out for hours but to no avail - what am I doing wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using case_when in a somewhat unorthodox way:

```r
## some data:

d <- cbind.data.frame(
    id = LETTERS,
    matrix(
        paste0(
            ceiling(runif(26*5, max=999)),
            sample( c("","B","K","M"), size=26*5, replace=T )
        ), nrow=26
    )
)

library(stringr)
library(readr)

d %>% mutate( across( -1,
                     ~ case_when(
                         str_detect(., 'B') ~ parse_number(as.character(.), na = c("", "NA")) * 1e9,
                         str_detect(., 'M') ~ parse_number(as.character(.), na = c("", "NA")) * 1e6,
                         str_detect(., 'K') ~ parse_number(as.character(.), na = c("", "NA")) * 1e3,
                         TRUE ~ parse_number(as.character(.), na = c("", "NA"), trim_ws = TRUE)
                     )
                     ))
```

Input data:

```
   id    1    2    3    4    5
1   A  834  27B  250 881B  988
2   B 313M 506B  309  413 141K
3   C  197   77  824 161B  43K
4   D 845K 172K 745B 922M 145M
5   E 168M 959M 990B 250K  893
6   F  430 687K 368M  10M 824M
7   G 940B 403B 655M  818 777K
8   H  281 833K  86B 849B  16K
9   I 485B 508B 349M 643M 926M
10  J 235B  10B 206M 505K 347M
11  K 897B 727M 405K 987B 674M
12  L 588B  40M 860M   58 934B
13  M 727K  375 188M 728K 201B
14  N 280K 442M  43K  400  445
15  O 988B 388M 530B 702M 240B
16  P 177M  782 410K 254K 758K
17  Q 706K  262 520B 104K   34
18  R 390B  99K 677K  965 635M
19  S  819 115M 920M 580M 295K
20  T 573M 901K  360   7K  88B
21  U 333B 593M 504B  992 241B
22  V  674 192M 841B 644B  659
23  W 524M 581M 692M   41  133
24  X 626K 686M 712K 756M 136B
25  Y  295  468 932M 486B  35K
26  Z 526K 798K 229K 958B 700B
```

Output:

```
   id        1        2        3        4        5
1   A 8.34e+02 2.70e+10 2.50e+02 8.81e+11 9.88e+02
2   B 3.13e+08 5.06e+11 3.09e+02 4.13e+02 1.41e+05
3   C 1.97e+02 7.70e+01 8.24e+02 1.61e+11 4.30e+04
4   D 8.45e+05 1.72e+05 7.45e+11 9.22e+08 1.45e+08
5   E 1.68e+08 9.59e+08 9.90e+11 2.50e+05 8.93e+02
6   F 4.30e+02 6.87e+05 3.68e+08 1.00e+07 8.24e+08
7   G 9.40e+11 4.03e+11 6.55e+08 8.18e+02 7.77e+05
8   H 2.81e+02 8.33e+05 8.60e+10 8.49e+11 1.60e+04
9   I 4.85e+11 5.08e+11 3.49e+08 6.43e+08 9.26e+08
10  J 2.35e+11 1.00e+10 2.06e+08 5.05e+05 3.47e+08
11  K 8.97e+11 7.27e+08 4.05e+05 9.87e+11 6.74e+08
12  L 5.88e+11 4.00e+07 8.60e+08 5.80e+01 9.34e+11
13  M 7.27e+05 3.75e+02 1.88e+08 7.28e+05 2.01e+11
14  N 2.80e+05 4.42e+08 4.30e+04 4.00e+02 4.45e+02
15  O 9.88e+11 3.88e+08 5.30e+11 7.02e+08 2.40e+11
16  P 1.77e+08 7.82e+02 4.10e+05 2.54e+05 7.58e+05
17  Q 7.06e+05 2.62e+02 5.20e+11 1.04e+05 3.40e+01
18  R 3.90e+11 9.90e+04 6.77e+05 9.65e+02 6.35e+08
19  S 8.19e+02 1.15e+08 9.20e+08 5.80e+08 2.95e+05
20  T 5.73e+08 9.01e+05 3.60e+02 7.00e+03 8.80e+10
21  U 3.33e+11 5.93e+08 5.04e+11 9.92e+02 2.41e+11
22  V 6.74e+02 1.92e+08 8.41e+11 6.44e+11 6.59e+02
23  W 5.24e+08 5.81e+08 6.92e+08 4.10e+01 1.33e+02
24  X 6.26e+05 6.86e+08 7.12e+05 7.56e+08 1.36e+11
25  Y 2.95e+02 4.68e+02 9.32e+08 4.86e+11 3.50e+04
26  Z 5.26e+05 7.98e+05 2.29e+05 9.58e+11 7.00e+11
```

See also other ways to convert the human readable byte number to a number, eg [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910688/converting-kilobytes-megabytes-etc-to-bytes-in-r) or perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62460848/function-library-to-convert-from-human-readable-size-to-byte-size)

Comment: This solved the issue, thank you so much for your help! Mutating it did the trick

Answer (score 0):

We could make use of `str_replace_all` instead of multiple `str_detect`.  Match and replace the 'B', 'M', 'K' substring in the column with a named vector in `str_replace_all`, then `separate` the column, and do the multiplication based on the separated columns

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
apple %>%
   mutate(col1 = str_replace_all(col1, setNames(c(' 1e9', ' 1e6', ' 1e3'), 
            c('B', 'M', 'K')))) %>%
   separate(col1, into = c('col1', 'col2'), convert = TRUE) %>%
   transmute(col1 = col1 * col2)
```

-output

```
#   col1
#1 4.0e+10
#2 2.0e+08
#3 2.0e+06
#4 4.0e+05
#5 3.6e+10
```

#### data

```
apple <- structure(list(col1 = c("40B", "200M", "2M", "400K", "36B")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This also seemed to work well